# Releasing memory in .NET - lists

Tags: vb.net

I read a post online earlier (not on StackOverflow), which stated that you should set lists (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to nothing once you have finished with them.  I cannot see any benefit whatsoever of doing this.

If list implemented IDisposable then I would wrap them in Using statements but they do not so I do not.

This has confused me a little bit.  I use to set variables to nothing once I had finished with them as I was under the false impression that this would encourage the garbage collector to free up the resource more quickly.  Is there ever a scenario where you should set a variable to nothing? and more specifically does this apply to lists?

Comment: Very vague, it depends on usage.  If the object that contains the list is likely to survive for a long time then using the List.Clear() method can be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know setting a variable to `Nothing` never helps, [even with COM objects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310263), where you need to do `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`. Lists are .NET objects, so they don't need any memory management. Unless you are experiencing memory issues. Then you may need to force garbage collection sooner / more often etc. Never had this opportunity in practice though.

Good thing you can do is always maintain a scope of your variables. If you don't need them to exist throughout the lifecycle of the application, declare them inside subs and functions where are used.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a list, which is an instance variable similar to this: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx#_self2 (see the real world example).  The list exists until the Stock class dies.  I don't believe this will cause memory issues but I wanted to check.  Do you agree? +1.

Comment: @w0051977: What is dofactory under the hood? Is it 100% managed code? If yes, you don't need to worry. If it's using any unmanaged code, you need to trust those guys to release memory when appropriate or don't use them. In any case you can always run a memory profiler included in Visual Studio, and see if you can spot any leaks. I never had to use it myself, .NET has always reliably released memory so far. If you stress test your software, you are likely to discover problems before they get into memory leaks.